# Why are errors nillable in Go?

Tags: go, error-handling, interface, null

An error in Go can be nil. The following compiles:

```
   var err error
   err = nil 
   err = errors.New("hello")
```

Yet [errors are values](https://blog.golang.org/errors-are-values), and value types are not nullable in Go.

Looking at `error`, it is an ordinary interface:

```
type error interface {
    Error() string
}
```

implemented by this struct:

```
type errorString struct {
    s string
}
```

No pointers here. There is  a method that takes a pointer receiver,

```
func (e *errorString) Error() string {
    return e.s
}
```

Yet that doesn't explain why `error` behaves as a pointer rather than a value.

`errors.New()` does return a pointer,

```
func New(text string) error {
    return &errorString{text}
}
```

which makes my third code line above more puzzling -- we are assigning the result of `New` to a value variable.

How does this work?

Comment: `error` is just an interface, and `nil` is a valid interface value.

Comment: Go has no concept of "value type" and thus your statement "value types are not nillable in Go" is vacuously false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you may be conflating some concepts. Yes, "errors are values", in that *they are not exceptions that can be thrown,* but rather they are *just regular values returned from a function like any other return value*. The Go quality "errors are values" has nothing to do with value vs reference semantics.

The built-in type `error` is an `interface`, and all interface values are nilable, so `error` is nilable.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. I am now deleting my question to avoid a downvote storm.

Comment: I will try closing it instead of deleting, since I think the answer is valuable. Let's see if the storm resumes :-)

Comment: @JoshuaFox (helped it get closed). Your question is merely off-topic for SO (as it's not about a particular problem but rather invokes a broad discussion touching language design philosophy). I mean, it would be fine on a mailing list or `r/programming` or `r/golang`.

Comment: Thank you. Apparently the downvote storm has stopped before zeroing me out :-) Thank  you for the answer.